# Sampling with replacement for bootstrapping [R]

Tags: r, statistics, mean, variance

I am relatively new to R, so I am just trying to see what I am missing. I have a few questions about the process of doing this correctly.

My sample space is {2,4,9,12}. I need to verify that the mean of this sample is 6.75, which it is if I input

```
s <- c(2,4,9,12)
mean(s)
```

I also need to calculate the variance of s, but when I calculate the variance
`var(s) = 20.91667`. The book I am reading, *Statistical Inference, Casella & Berger*, shows that the variance is 3.94. Now, I know since I am bootstrapping there is a different method, where instead of the sample variance being divided by (n-1), it is divided by ((n^n)-1) and it needs to be summed from i = 1 all they way up to (n^n). For easier understanding, screenshot of this formula will be posted here:

[image: Bootstrap variance formula]

**Question 1**

Is there a function implemented within R that finds the bootstrap mean and variance that can help me verify this answer? If so, can an example be provided on how to do so?

**Question 2**

For my own curiosity. Let's say that I wanted to bootstrap that sample space (not sure if that makes too much sense). How do I find the bootstrap mean and variance of a sample WITH replacement and loop that over for 10,000 samples?

Bear with me on this, because like I had mentioned, I am new to R and this concept of bootstrapping. Please correct me if my thought process is not exactly right. So, for example, when I input `sample(c(2,4,9,12), replace = T, 10000)`, it gives me 10,000 elements, but I want 10,000 vectors of length of 4. In other words, when I input `sample(c(2,4,9,12), replace = T, 1)`, it only gives one value, but I would like it to be a vector of 4 with any order of those four values WITH replacement. Now, once all 10,000 vectors (assuming that it is not the SAME vector repeated are created, I want to be able to find the bootstrap mean and variance of each vector. Once I have these means and variances, I want to be able to create a distribution graph to observe the CLT visually.

I am aware that my conceptual understanding of bootstrapping may be flawed, so please, I urge you to give me pointers to solidify my understanding.

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing's first: The variance of the sample mean and the variance of the sample are two different quantities. When you do `var(s)` and get `20.91`, you're calculating the variance of the sample, not of the sample mean. So now, on to your questions:

I'm sure there are functions to run the bootstrap, but my advice would be to do it from scratch. It's only about 10 lines of code. Something like this might work:

```r
s <- c(2,4,9,12)

N <- 10**5
sample_means <- numeric(N)

for (i in 1:N) {
    resample <- sample(s, replace = TRUE)
    sample_means[i] <- mean(resample)
}

mean(sample_means)
#> [1] 6.752375
var(sample_means)
#> [1] 3.941898
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could also use `purrr` for a more elegant solution (in my opinion, at least):

```r
library(purrr)

s <- c(2,4,9,12)

N <- 10**5
sample_means <- rerun(
    .n = N,
    sample(s, replace = TRUE)
) %>%
    map_dbl(mean)

sample_means %>%
    mean()
#> [1] 6.75615

sample_means %>%
    var()
#> [1] 3.965604
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Then, if you wanted to use the code above to make a histogram of the sample means, you'd just do

```r
hist(sample_means)
```

Comment: You could replace the `for`-loop by `apply(replicate(10000, sample(c(2,4,9,12), replace = TRUE, 4)), 2, mean)`.

Comment: Yep, thanks @MartinGal! I thought the for loop was a little bit more expressive as far as base R solutions go, but there are tons of ways of doing this :)

Comment: Good explanation, btw.